# How to refuse endorsing transactions as an organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I always have a theoretical and general question in my mind: let's assume that there are two orgs: org1 and org2. And each org has one peer. If the endorsement policy is set to AND(org1, org2), which means that every transaction needs the endorsement from both org1 and org2's peer.

Let's assume a scenario: org1 and org2 have already endorsed 5 transactions. But some day, let's say, org1 doesn't want to endorse any transaction at all, which means that for every new incoming transaction(e.g. 6th transaction), org1 wants to say no, and refuses to endorse the new transaction. So my question is:
How can org1 refuse endorsing new incoming transaction? In more vivid words, as an org, how to say no? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by refusing endorsement, if a request is not endorsed the transaction will not happen. is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An endorsement is not an option, where a user chooses between yes and no. The transactions are executed in the peers having chaincode and when the peers, as specified by the endorsement policy, agree on the result then the transaction is said to be endorsed. The process of execution of a transaction may depend upon the ledgers of the peer. For example, all the peers have stored in the ledger that Ram has 50 value `Ram:50`, now the new transaction adds 20 value to Ram's account. This gets executed in the endorsing peers and the added result `Ram:70` is agreed by all the peers. Now the transaction will be endorsed. But if the ledger of one peer is altered as `Ram:40` and that peer needs to endorse the transaction, it will come up with a result of `Ram:60` which won't match the result of rest of the peers and the transaction will not be endorsed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I feel I understand more than before. Can I understand like this:let's assume that there are two orgs:org1 and org2. Endorsement policy AND(org1,org2) can make sure that if either org1 or org2 modify the ledger arbitrarily and maliciously, the new transaction will not be endorsed, right?

Comment: OK. Got it. An extended question: if endorsement policy is set to OR(org1,org2), does it mean that either org1 or org2 has the possibility to modify the ledger based on their willing arbitrarily, and eventually make the new incoming transaction endorsed successfully and committed to ledger? For example, take your example, org1 modify value of Ram from 50 to 40, and a new transaction is to increase this value by 20, so the eventual is 60, and can possibly be committed to ledger?

Comment: Yes, you could see that by doing so. Change the values of state database and try to send a transaction. But while quering the value, if you query just from a single peer, it will show you the value of the peer's database which could be malicious too. So, in that case you should target the all or most of the peers in the channel.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually pull this off with a little [custom pluggable code](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L321-L335) which can be loaded at the startup of the peer.
What you need to do, is to create an authentication filter which will prevent endorsements and return errors instead of forwarding the request to the next authentication filter.

From the [core.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/sampleconfig/core.yaml) file:

```
    handlers:
        authFilters:
          -
            name: DefaultAuth
          -
            name: ExpirationCheck    # This filter checks identity x509 certificate expiration
```

These are the default built-in filters that exist in the peer. For example - the ExpirationCheck filter - [checks for expiration](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go#L49-L52) of the identity of the client.

What you need to do, is to add another filter which simply refuses proposals from clients (let's name it - NopeFilter) and then compile it to a golang plugin, and add the following entry:

```
-  
  name: FilterOne
  library: /opt/lib/filter.so
```

The content of the filter will be very similar to the [DefaulAuth](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go) filter (which does nothing):

```
func (nf *NopeFilter) ProcessProposal(ctx context.Context, signedProp *peer.SignedProposal) (*peer.ProposalResponse, error) {
    return nil, errors.New("nope")
}
```

At peer startup, the list of filters is read from the core.yaml section, and is then [chained into a chain of filters](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/handlers/auth/auth.go#L23-L37) which either reject the proposal, or pass it to the next filter.

The last filter is always the real endorser service in the peer, which actually performs the chaincode execution and endorsement (signing the results).

Comment: Thanks very much for so detailed code level answer. This makes me know the code can be pluggable and custom. In future I will follow the steps in your answer if the business requirement needs this.